# Как добавить подпункт в json файле используя python

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Есть json файл такого формата:

```
"order_id": {
    "done": "False",
    "date": "date",
    "time": "time_",
    "address": "address",
    "category": "category",
    "comm": "main_com",
    "user": "user",
    "create_date": "create_date",
    "live_time": "live_time",
    "area": "area",
    "count": "count",
    "details": {
        "main_comment": "main_comment",
        "comment_1": {
            "date_comm": "date_comm",
            "user_comm": "user_comm",
            "comment": "comment"
        },
        "comment_2": {
            "date_comm": "date_comm",
            "user_comm": "user_comm",
            "comment": "comment"
        },
        "comment_3": {
            "date_comm": "date_comm",
            "user_comm": "user_comm",
            "comment": "comment"
        }
    }
}
```

Необходимо так сказать динамически устанавливать количество "comment_1", их может быть как 1, так и 10 и каждый необходимо выносить в отдельный подпункт, например всего с одним комментом или с семью в отдельном ордере

C json не шибко знаком, поэтому не могу понять как менять количество подпунктов в зависимости от информации на сервере, надеюсь на вашу помощь

Comment: `json_['order_id']['details']['comment_4'] = {'date_comm': ... }` или про что вопрос?

Comment: именно это и имел ввиду